# Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm not working for large limits

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have programmed a sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm in C++, and it works fine for smaller numbers that I have tested it with. However, when I use large numbers, i.e. 2 000 000 as the upper limit, the program begins giving wrong answers. Can anyone clarify why?

Your help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    clock_t a, b;
    a = clock();

    int n = 0, k = 2000000; // n = Sum of primes, k = Upper limit
    bool r[k - 2]; // r = All numbers below k and above 1 (if true, it has been marked as a non-prime)
    for(int i = 0; i < k - 2; i++) // Check all numbers
        if(!r[i]) { // If it hasn't been marked as a non-prime yet ...
            n += i + 2; // Add the prime to the total sum (+2 because of the shift - index 0 is 2, index 1 is 3, etc.)
            for(int j = 2 * i + 2; j < k - 2; j += i + 2) // Go through all multiples of the prime under the limit
                r[j] = true; // Mark the multiple as a non-prime
        }

    b = clock();
    cout << "Final Result: " << n << endl;
    cout << b - a << "ms runtime achieved." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I just did some debugging and found that it works with the limit at around 400. At 500, however, it is off - it should be 21536, but is 21499

EDIT 2: Ah, I found two errors and those seem to have fixed the problem.

The first was found by others who answered, and is that n is overflowing - upon being made a long long data type, it  has begun working.

The second, rather facepalm-worthy mistake, was that the booleans in r had to be initialized. After running loop before checking for primes to make all of them false, the right answer is gotten. Does anyone know why this occured?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by identifying the first point where your program's behaviour diverges from what you expect.

Comment: What is your expected answer?  Does it fit in the variable type you are using?

Comment: Which C++ version are you using?  The `bool r[k-2]` may have allocation problems.  Try converting `k` to a `#define`. Try using `std::vector<bool>`

Comment: Ah, that's true, maybe the integer isn't enough to hold it - I'll trying a long/long long - I'll also try converting the k

Edit: The integer wasn't holding it enough, you're right, but the answer is still wrong. I got 142899845759, it should be 142913828922

Comment: you might need to use `unsigned` to avoid overflow in the inner loop, [example](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#C.2B.2B)

Comment: I don't think so - it stops working with 500 - would an integer really not be able to hold ~500?

Comment: Just for clarity, this is supposed to be producing the *sum* of all primes, including `1`, between 0 and `k`, where in this case `k` is two-million? (and furthering clarity, the last prime below 2000000 is 1999993, so we're on the same page, is that what you're looking for?)

Answer (score 2):

You simply get an integer overflow. The C++ type `int` is has a limited range (on a 32 bit System usually from -(2^32) / 2 to 2^32 / 2 - 1, that is the usual maximum is 2147483647 (The specific maximum on your setup can be found out by #including the `<limits>` header and evaluating `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`. Even when k is smaller than the maximum, your code will sooner or later cause an overflow in the expressions `n += i + 2` or `int j = 2 * i + 2`.

You will have to choose a better (read: more appropriate) type like `unsigned` which does not support negative numbers and can thus can represent numbers twice as large as `int`. You can also try `unsigned long` or even `unsigned long long`.

Also note that variable length arrays (VLAs; that's what `bool r[k - 2]` is) are not standard C++. You might want to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. You also did not initialize the array to `false` (`std::vector` would do this automatically), which could also be the problem, especially if you say that it does not work even at k=500.

In C++, you should also use `<ctime>` instead of `<time.h>` (then `clock_t` and `and`clock()`are defined in the`std`namespace, but since you are`using namespace std`, this won't make a difference for you), but this is more or less a matter of style.

I found a working example in my "code archive". Although it is not based on yours, you might find it useful:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<bool> marked_t;
    typedef marked_t::size_type number_t; // The type used for indexing marked_t.

    const number_t max = 500;

    static const number_t iDif = 2; // Account for the numbers 1 and 2.
    marked_t marked(max - iDif);
    number_t i = iDif;

    while (i*i <= max) {
        while (marked[i - iDif] == true)
            ++i;
        for (number_t fac = iDif; i * fac < max; ++fac)
            marked[i * fac - iDif] = true;
        ++i;
    }

    for (marked_t::size_type i = 0; i < marked.size(); ++i) {
        if (!marked[i])
            std::cout << i + iDif << ',';
    }
}
```